# displaying domain's NS in Vue client project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have created an input and button in my project. the user is supposed to enter domain name and get its NS by clicking on button through a node JS function that returns nameserver.

`getNs.js` file in @/plugins/

```
export function getNs(domain) {
  const dns = require('node:dns');
  const dnsPromises = dns.promises;
  const options = {
   family: 6,
   hints: dns.ADDRCONFIG | dns.V4MAPPED,
 };

 options.all = true;
  dnsPromises.resolveNs(domain, options).then((result) => {
  console.log('addresses: %j', result);
  return result
 });
}
```

declaring function in component script:

importing the plugin:

```
import {getIp} from "~/services/displayIp";
```

in `methods`:

```
goToSecondStep() {
  getIp()
}
```

the event is happening on the button:

```
@click="goToSecondStep"
```

the error i get:
This dependency was not found:                                                                                                                                             friendly-errors 09:54:39
friendly-errors 09:54:39

- node:dns in ./services/displayIp.js                                                                                                                                   friendly-errors 09:54:39
  friendly-errors 09:54:39
  To install it, you can run: npm install --save node:dns

i get the same error even though i run `npm install --save node:dns` command.

how can i use node js function or plugins in vuejs temeplates.

Comment: Do you have a Node server running somewhere? Vue is meant to be client side only. Also, check that you properly have the package in your `package.json`. Finally, a serverless function or a middleware backend could help in your case.

Comment: @kissu oh thanks btw we have a servermiddleware i can use that

Comment: Nuxt2 app? Tried to deploy that one already?